# iOS - How to get multiple .ipa files fully automatic within one build, with different icon and display name

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

Recently we want to generate hundreds of custom .ipa files, the only difference of them is with different icon and app display name, is there anyway that can get multiple .ipa files automatically, or other possible solution.

Comment: Perhaps, scripts can help you: http://testdroid.com/tech/tipstricks-how-to-archive-and-export-ipa-from-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create Multiple Targets/Apps for 1 Xcode Project with different icon and app name, You can try this: http://samwize.com/2014/05/22/create-multiple-targets-slash-apps-for-1-xcode-project/

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, you saved my life.  After all these steps just add a run script to each target will work perfect